# Replace a pattern in file with the header of that specific column with perl

Tags: perl, bash

I'm working with the following file format:

```
POS1    POS2    ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 …
1   ### 0/0:.:58:.:.    0/0:.:51:.:.    0/0:.:104:.:.   0/0:.:16:.:.    
2   ### 0/0:89:.:.:.    0/0:75:.:.:.    0/0:125:.:.:.   0/0:57:.:.:.    
3   ### 0/0:.:93:.:.    0/0:.:85:.:.    0/0:.:127:.:.   0/0:.:60:.:.    
4   ### .:.:.:.:.   0/0:7:.:.:. .:.:.:.:.   .:.:.:.:.   
5   ### .:.:.:.:.   .:.:.:.:.   .:.:.:.:.   .:.:.:.:.   
6   ### .:.:.:.:.   0/0:8:.:.:. .:.:.:.:.   .:.:.:.:.   
7   ### 0/0:24:.:.:.    0/0:41:.:.:.    0/0:17:.:.:.    0/0:33:.:.:.    
8   ### 0/0:39:.:.:.    0/0:59:.:.:.    0/1:68:.:.:.    0/0:77:.:.:.    
9   ### 0/0:.:18:.:.    0/0:.:36:.:.    0/0:.:26:.:.    0/0:.:38:.:.    
10  ### 0/0:.:18:.:.    0/0:.:32:.:.    0/0:.:24:.:.    0/0:.:34:.:.    
11  ### 0/1:18:.:.:.    0/0:28:.:.:.    0/0:24:.:.:.    0/0:34:.:.:.    
12  ### 0/0:.:13:.:.    0/0:.:22:.:.    0/0:.:23:.:.    0/0:.:35:.:.    
13  ### 0/0:.:25:.:.    0/0:.:30:.:.    0/0:.:34:.:.    0/0:.:38:.:.    
14  ### 0/0:20:.:.:.    0/0:28:.:.:.    0/0:34:.:.:.    0/0:39:.:.:.    
15  ### 0/0:19:.:.:.    0/0:27:.:.:.    0/0:32:.:.:.    0/0:39:.:.:.    
16  ### .:.:.:.:.   0/0:26:.:.:.    0/1:34:.:.:.    0/0:32:.:.:.    
17  ### .:.:.:.:.   .:.:.:.:.   0/0:.:9:.:. 0/0:.:13:.:.
```

The problem I'm having is trying to list the ID's per position that contain a "0/1" pattern. Even if you guys could only figure out how I could replace the "0/1" with that specific column ID, I could work the rest out myself. The amount of columns and rows are very variable, possible thousands.

Differently formulated: If a position contains an ID with a "0/1" in that row it should list the column ID of the column it found the "0/1" in

Is it possible to work through this problem with perl (or bash) and how? I'm still somewhat of a newbie at the language, having known it for only 4 weeks.

My thanks in forward.

EDIT
Sample output should be something like this:

```
POS1 POS2   
8   ### ID3
11  ### ID1
16  ### ID3
```

If more than one columns contain a 0/1 it should all ID's for that position.
Sorry if I sound a bit confusing, long day at the office.

Comment: Can you show us some sample output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this? The program expects the input file as a parameter on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @headers;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /\t/;
  if (@headers) {
    my @ids;
    for my $i (2 .. $#fields) {
      push @ids, $headers[$i] if $fields[$i] =~ m:0/1:;
    }
    print join("\t", $fields[0], @ids), "\n" if @ids;
  }
  else {
    @headers = @fields;
    print join("\t", @headers[0,1]), "\n";
  }
}
```

**output**

```
POS1  POS2
8 ID3
11  ID1
16  ID3
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Guess I need to polish my array knowledge up a bit '^^

Comment: **Note** fixed since you updated your question. Thanks for the additional help.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    NR==1 {for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) head[i]=$i; print $1, $2; next}
    {
        line = $1 OFS $2
        found = 0
        for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ($i ~ /0\/1/) {
                found = 1
                line = line OFS head[i]
            }
        }
        if (found) print line
    }
' file
```

or bash

```
file="filename.txt"
headers=( $(head -1 "$file") )
sed '1d' "$file" | while read -a fields; do      
    out=( ${fields[0]} ${fields[1]} )
    found=false
    for (( i=2; i<${#fields[@]}; i++ )); do          
        if [[ ${fields[i]} == *0/1* ]]; then              
            out+=(${headers[i]})
            found=true
        fi
    done
    $found && echo "${out[*]}"
done > output.txt
```